# cURL, load multiple addresses from file and echo the output to multiple files

Tags: bash, curl

bash noob here, trying to do something with curl.

I have a file with a bunch of URLs like

`http://www.something.com/bla`

`http://www.something.com/bla/bleh`

`http://www.something.com/bleurgh`

I know of curls ability to handle multiple requests via

curl http://www.something.com/{bla, bla/bleh, bleurgh}

and I'd like to output each request to a separate file, something like

`http://www.something.com/bla` would output to bla.html
`http://www.something.com/bla/bleh` would output to bla_bleh.html
etc.

is there a quick and easy way to do this with curl and bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say:

```
for i in bla bla/bleh bleurgh; do
  curl -O "${i//\//_}.html" "http://www.something.com/${i}"
done
```